# Rewriting function to conditional CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function, common-table-expression

**Considering following table:**

```
SELECT [ItemID]
      ,[ParentID]
      ,[PolicyID]
      ,[PolicyRoot]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[dbo].[Example]


ItemID      ParentID    PolicyID   PolicyRoot
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
1           NULL        default    1
2           1           b          1
3           1           c          0
4           NULL        d          1
5           3           e          0
6           3           f          1
7           NULL        g          0
```

I'm trying to select the `PolicyID` from each item where `PolicyRoot = 1`, in case `PolicyRoot = 0` I need to use `PolicyID` from its `ParentID`. This is recursive...

**Working with a function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Policies(@ItemID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ParentID INT, @PolicyRoot BIT, @PolicyID VARCHAR(10)

    SELECT  @ParentID = ParentID
    ,       @PolicyRoot = PolicyRoot
    ,       @PolicyID = PolicyID
    FROM    [dbo].[Example]
    WHERE   ItemID = @ItemID

    IF      @PolicyRoot != 1
            SELECT @PolicyID = dbo.Policies(@ParentID)
    RETURN  @PolicyID
END;

GO

SELECT  ItemID
,       dbo.Policies(ItemID) AS Policy 
FROM    [dbo].[Example];


ItemID      Policy
----------- ----------
1           default
2           b
3           default
4           d
5           default
6           f
7           NULL
```

I'm trying to rewrite this function to a CTE, but I don't have any CTE knowledge yet. I've read into multiple CTE's but I don't have a single clue how to manage a conditional CTE. This is as far as I've gotten, I'm not familiar (enough) with the `UNION ALL`.

```
WITH Policies (ItemID, PolicyID) AS (
    SELECT  ItemID
    ,       PolicyID
    FROM    dbo.Example

    UNION ALL

    ...
)
SELECT  ItemID
,       PolicyID
FROM    Policies;
```

Can someone explain me in plain steps how such a CTE works and push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive CTE works by joining to itself, using a `UNION ALL` to collate the results.

You start with yourtable to populate the initial dataset of the recursive query

```
    select * from yourtable
```

and you add to that with the `UNION ALL`, further results

```
    select c.ItemID, t2.ParentID, t2.PolicyID, t2.PolicyRoot
    from yourtable t2
        inner join c on c.ParentID = t2.ItemID 
      where c.PolicyRoot=0
```

and the recursion occurs in this - where the results of this query are fed through this query again and again, up to the `MAXRECURSION` limit, or when no more results are added.

```
;with c as 
(
    select * from yourtable
    union all
    select c.ItemID, t2.ParentID, t2.PolicyID, t2.PolicyRoot
    from yourtable t2
        inner join c on c.ParentID = t2.ItemID 
      where c.PolicyRoot=0
)
select t.ItemID, c.PolicyID 
      from yourtable t
     left join c on t.ItemID = c.ItemID 
                 and c.PolicyRoot=1
```